# Insert JSON into Mysql problem (ajax/php)

Tags: php, mysql, json, ajax

I have a Json that I build after dropping a tab separated text into a text area (from this [codepen](https://codepen.io/kibblewhite/pen/mVVOBN) example):

```
[
  {
    "0": "2019-08-31",
    "1": "Bank Exp.",
    "2": "EUR"
  },
  {
    "0": "2019-08-31",
    "1": "Legal",
    "2": "EUR"
  },
  {
    "0": "2019-08-31",
    "1": "Legal",
    "2": "EUR"
  }
]
```

and is stored in variable:

```
jsonString = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
```

I then pass this json via ajax to a php file

```
var options = {
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "test.php",
                  data: { test: jsonString },
                  dataType: 'json',
                  success: function( data, status, xhr ) {
                    alert ("php:"+data);

                  },
                  error: function( xhr, status, error ) {
                   alert (data);
                  }
                };
                $.ajax( options );
```

to process a simple MYSQL insert of the different rows in the columns 0, 1, 2 in my 'test.php' file:

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$user="renaud";
$pass="Mod100572$";
$db="accounting";
$con= new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db) or die("ERROR:could not connect to the database!!!");
$test = utf8_encode($_POST['test']);
$data_array = json_decode($test);
foreach($data_array as $row) {

    $query .= "INSERT INTO `test` set
          `field1`  = '".$row['0']."',
          `field2`  = '".$row['1']."',
          `field3`  = '".$row["2"]."';";
}
if(mysqli_multi_query($con, $query)) {
    $msg = "success";
} else {
    $msg = "Something wrong! Please try again.";
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I Apparently do not achieve to convert my '$_POST['test']' into a correct array and the loop only gets '[' values. It is considered as a string, not an array.

I tried other parameters such as  $data_array = json_decode($test,`true`); with no luck.

Any help to understand my error is deeply appreciated...

Comment: As you are using `$row['0']` - you should decode the data using `$data_array = json_decode($test,true);`.  Have you tried to debug it with something like `var_dump($data_array);`?

Comment: Also noticed - you don't set `$query` before the loop, I would always use something like `$query = "";` to make sure.

Comment: Try to avoid `mysqli_multi_query` as much as you can. You don't need to use it and it could be very dangerous when misused.

Answer (score 0):

Insert syntax error

`$query .= "INSERT INTO`test`VALUES (`
field1`= '".$row['0']."',`
field2`= '".$row['1']."',`
field3`= '".$row["2"]."');";`